# how to set ImageView background in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am using API level 14. `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated and `setBackground` complains of being for API level 16. So what do I use to set my background drawable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setBackgroundDrawable()` for API 14 and 15 and `setBackground()` for API 16+:

```
int currentVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (currentVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    imageView.setBackground(...);
}
else{
    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(...);
}
```

Comment: When I do, it complains about being deprecated.

Comment: You need to decorate method or line of code (depending on what makes sense) like `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`

Answer (score 5):

Suppress the Lint warning, and add this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16){
            imageView.setBackground(drawable);
        }else{
            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        }
```